# Sqoop incremental load lastmodified not working on updated records

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I'm working on a sqoop incremental job to load data from mysql to hdfs. Below is the following scenarios.

**Scenario 1:**
Below are the records inserted in sample table in mysql.

```
select * from sample;
+-----+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id  | policy | salary | updated_time        |
+-----+--------+--------+---------------------+
| 100 |      1 |   4567 | 2017-08-02 01:58:28 |
| 200 |      2 |   3456 | 2017-08-02 01:58:29 |
| 300 |      3 |   2345 | 2017-08-02 01:58:29 |
+-----+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

Below is the table structure of sample table in mysql:

```
create table sample (id int not null primary key, policy int, salary int, updated_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I'm trying to import this to hdfs by creating a sqoop job as below

```
sqoop job --create incjob -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root -P --table sample --merge-key id --split-by id --target-dir /user/cloudera --append --incremental lastmodified --check-column updated_time -m 1
```

After executing sqoop job below is the output records in hdfs.

```
$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/par*
100,1,4567,2017-08-02 01:58:28.0
200,2,3456,2017-08-02 01:58:29.0
300,3,2345,2017-08-02 01:58:29.0
```

**Scenario 2:** After inserting few new records and updating existing records in sample table. Below is the sample table.

```
select * from sample;
+-----+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id  | policy | salary | updated_time        |
+-----+--------+--------+---------------------+
| 100 |      6 |   5638 | 2017-08-02 02:01:09 |
| 200 |      2 |   7654 | 2017-08-02 02:01:10 |
| 300 |      3 |   2345 | 2017-08-02 01:58:29 |
| 400 |      4 |   1234 | 2017-08-02 02:01:17 |
| 500 |      5 |   6543 | 2017-08-02 02:01:18 |
+-----+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

After running the same sqoop job below is the records in hdfs.

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/par*
100,1,4567,2017-08-02 01:58:28.0
200,2,3456,2017-08-02 01:58:29.0
300,3,2345,2017-08-02 01:58:29.0
100,6,5638,2017-08-02 02:01:09.0
200,2,7654,2017-08-02 02:01:10.0
400,4,1234,2017-08-02 02:01:17.0
500,5,6543,2017-08-02 02:01:18.0
```

Here the updated records in mysql are inserted as new records in hdfs, instead of updating the existing records in hdfs. I have used both --merge-key as well as --append in my sqoop job conf. Could any help me on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `--merge-key` `--append` and `lastmodified` together. This is nor correct.

- `--incremental append` mode Append data to an existing dataset in HDFS. You should specify append mode when importing a table where new rows are continually being added with increasing row id values
- `--incremental lastmodified` mode - You should use this when rows of the source table may be updated, and each such update will set the value of a last-modified column to the current timestamp.
- `--merge-key` - The merge tool runs a MapReduce job that takes two directories as input: a newer dataset, and an older one. These are specified with --new-data and --onto respectively. The output of the MapReduce job will be placed in the directory in HDFS specified by `--target-dir`.
- `--last-value` (value)   Specifies the maximum value of the check column from the previous import. If you run sqoop from the command line, without Sqoop job, then you have to add `--last-value` parameter

In your case there are some new record and some records are also updated so you need go with `lastmodified` mode.

Your Sqoop command will be:

`sqoop job --create incjob -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root -P --table sample --merge-key id --target-dir /user/cloudera --incremental lastmodified --check-column updated_time -m 1`

Since you have specified only one mapper there is no need of `--split-by`.

Comment: for sqoop job the last-value is not recommended to be mentioned as it gets updated for every time it gets exectuted. It takes the last-value from sqoop metastore.

Comment: Ideally you should specify `--last-value` in this way to ensure you import only the new or updated data. This is handled automatically by creating an incremental import as a saved job, which is the preferred mechanism for performing a recurring incremental import.

Comment: True.. but this was not working for me. I tried many ways but not able to update existing records in hdfs thru sqoop incremental

Comment: You are using `--merge-key` and `--append` together. Please remove the `--append`

Comment: `--append` - Append data to an existing dataset in HDFS and therefore you are not getting the desired result.

Comment: I have updated the answer with detail. Please check it above.

Comment: I used the same command as u mentioned above but it failed for the second time load. In the first load it creates a separate folder and put the part file in that. When i run for the second time it failed throwing below error.

Comment: INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1501748863702_0014_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /user/cloudera/b9bef88b36484b89b13ad9a5759adfad_sample

Comment: The difference what i saw with and without using append arg is that. With using append it creates the part file in the same folder (/user/cloudera). Without using append it creates a separate folder inside cloudera folder (/user/cloudera/b9bef88b36484b89b13ad9a5759adfad_sample).

Comment: $> sqoop job --create incjob -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root -P --table sample --merge-key id --target-dir /user/cloudera --incremental lastmodified --check-column updated_time -m 1 --last-value 0

Comment: First Load:
$> sqoop job --exec incjob

Output:
17/08/03 03:34:16 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 99 bytes in 24.6205 seconds (4.021 bytes/sec)
17/08/03 03:34:16 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 3 records.
17/08/03 03:34:52 INFO tool.ImportTool: Saving incremental import state to the metastore
17/08/03 03:34:52 INFO tool.ImportTool: Updated data for job: incjob

Comment: Second Load:
$> sqoop job --exec incjob

Output:
7/08/03 03:37:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1501748863702_0014
17/08/03 03:37:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1501748863702_0014 running in uber mode : false
17/08/03 03:37:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/08/03 03:37:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1501748863702_0014_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /user/cloudera/b9bef88b36484b89b13ad9a5759adfad_sample

Answer (score 0):

1. I understand that you are trying to update the existing records in HDFS whenever there is change happens in the Source MySQL table.
2. You should use --append only when you dont want to update the changed records in source table.
3. Another approach is you can to try to migrate the changed records in a separate directory as delta_records and then join it with the base_records. Please see hortonworks [link](https://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/) for more clarity